# Let convex $\square ABCD$ have $\angle DAC=\angle ACD=17^\circ$; $\angle CAB=30^\circ$; and $\angle BCA = 43^{\circ}$. Compute $\angle ABD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $\square ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral with $\angle DAC = \angle ACD = 17^{\circ}$; $\angle CAB = 30^{\circ}$; and $\angle BCA = 43^{\circ}$.  Compute $\angle ABD$.

What I have so far:

Since $\angle DAC = \angle ACD = 17^{\circ}$ , points $A$, $C$, and $D$ form an isosceles triangle. We can look at the circle with center $D$ and radius $|DA|=|DC|$.

I believe this can help because one can then look at the angles subtended by the arc $AC$ and use them to gain further information. (I have seen this done in a similar problem.) I can't seem to find any angles that are $\frac{146}2=73^{\circ}$, though, so this is probably wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this a circular quadrilateral (has a circumcircle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reflex $\angle ADC=360^{\circ}-146^{\circ}=214^{\circ}=2\times 107^{\circ}=2\times \angle ABC$

Since the angle subtended at the center of a circle is double the angle subtended at the circumference, above proves that our constructed circle also passes through the point $B$. So, $|DA|=|DB|=|DC|$ which in turn means that $\angle ABD=\angle BAD=\angle DAC+\angle BAC=47^{\circ}$.

Comment: Did you pay attention at "reflex"? According to the question which I think I've solved correctly, $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral whose vertex $D$ can be thought of as lying on the center of a circle with the other three lying on the circumference.